# Element or $(element) in a directive

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive

In a lecture Deep dive into custom directives Dave Smith gives an example:

```
.directive('selectAll', function () {
  return {
      restrict: 'A',
      link: function( scope, element ) {
        element.mouseup( function ( event ) {
          event.preventDefault();
        } );
        element.focus( function () {
          element.select();
        } );
      }
  };
})
```

but as a result I have an error:

```
TypeError: undefined is not a function
at link (http://localhost:8080/modules.html:108:21)
at invokeLinkFn (http://localhost:8080/lib/angular.js:8111:9)
at nodeLinkFn (http://localhost:8080/lib/angular.js:7623:11)
at compositeLinkFn (http://localhost:8080/lib/angular.js:6991:13)
at compositeLinkFn (http://localhost:8080/lib/angular.js:6994:13)
at publicLinkFn (http://localhost:8080/lib/angular.js:6870:30)
at http://localhost:8080/lib/angular.js:1489:27
at Scope.$eval (http://localhost:8080/lib/angular.js:14123:28)
at Scope.$apply (http://localhost:8080/lib/angular.js:14221:23)
at bootstrapApply (http://localhost:8080/lib/angular.js:1487:15)
```

When I put `$(element)` instead of `element` everything is fine:

```
.directive('selectAll', function () {
  return {
      restrict: 'A',
      link: function( scope, element ) {
        $(element).mouseup( function ( event ) {
          event.preventDefault();
        } );
        $(element).focus( function () {
          $(element).select();
        } );
      }
  };
})
```

2 questions: why? and how to make the first behavior a default?

Comment: `element.bind( 'focus',function ( event ) {` ...

Comment: anything simpler than bind'ing?

Comment: What's the problem with JQuery's `$(element).focus(...)`?

Comment: If you want to to do this just using angular, `keyup` and `focus` will only be avaiable using angular `elm.bind()` if you include [angular ui](http://angular-ui.github.io/)

Comment: the question is more about how to make the first code working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They should be equivalent if you are including the jquery library in the correct order. Make sure that you are including the jQuery library before the angularjs library.

Answer (score 3):

Yeah, this can be confusing.

Angular uses jQLite, a subset of jQuery. `$(element)` would be a jquery object, and could therefore have jquery functions called upon it. Calling `document.createElement('div').css("background", "green"), for instance, would not work because it is not a jquery-wrapped element.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Also, if ever in doubt or curious about something... console.log() it!

Answer (score 1):

From AngularJS documentation:

> If jQuery is available, angular.element is an alias for the jQuery
>   function. If jQuery is not available, angular.element delegates to
>   Angular's built-in subset of jQuery, called "jQuery lite" or "jqLite."

Since jqLite implements only the most commonly needed functionality, if you want to use "element.select" and not "$(element).select" you need to load jQuery library **before DOMContentLoaded event fired**.

Now **angular.element** will be an alias of jQuery function and then those two pieces of code will be equivalent.